# save datatable data to database

Tags: javascript, django, datatable

I am trying to create a website using Django. I am not familiar with javascript. So I am having hard time in figuring out an issue. In the website, there is a table which I should be able to edit online and the edit should be reflected to the database. I am using the datatable editor example from the below link as the original datatable editor needs a dedicated license.   The script(indented below) is what I am using in my html file instead of whats there on the jsfiddle. I want to save the data to database once I edit any field on the website.

http://jsfiddle.net/rmcmaster/bbLjzspf/22/

```
    <script>
          $(document).ready(function() {

            var dataSet = [

                    {% for data_i in table_data %}
                [{{data_i.name}}, {{data_i.Position}}, {{data_i.Office}}, {{data_i.Salary}}] ,              
                {% endfor %}
            ];

            var columnDefs = [{
              title: "Name"
            }, {
              title: "Position"
            }, {
              title: "Office"
            }, {
              title: "Salary"
            }];

            var myTable;

            myTable = $('#example').DataTable({
              "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
              data: dataSet,
              columns: columnDefs,
              dom: 'Bfrtip',        // Needs button container
              select: 'single',
              responsive: true,
              altEditor: true,     // Enable altEditor
              buttons: [{
                text: 'Add',
                name: 'add'        // do not change name
              },
              {
                extend: 'selected', // Bind to Selected row
                text: 'Edit',
                name: 'edit'        // do not change name
              },
              {
                extend: 'selected', // Bind to Selected row
                text: 'Delete',
                name: 'delete'      // do not change name
             }]

            });

          });
</script>
```

Comment: JavaScript is executed on frontend. It doesn't have direct connection to your DB, you will have to add view(controler) which will accept edited data from frontend which you will post with JS to your django server

Comment: you can write ajax functions for the edit functionality.